# Skip firebase existing data checking

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Can I actually skip the duplicate data checking?

example, when an user comes to my site. First I will check if the user exists else we create the user.

```
users
 - uid1
   - name: 'Beck'
 - uid2
   - name: 'Ronaldinho'
```

As above, the uid1 is already exists. Can I simply use the below code.

```
    $firebaseSimpleLogin(dataRef).$login(provider).then(function(user) {
                dataRef.child('users/' + user.uid).set(user, function() {
                    console.log('redirect to home');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe not. Set will 'overwrite any data at this location and all child locations'. Check docs for set [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/set.html)

Comment: The docs you refer are indeed what is relevant here. But I explain it (and experienced them) as being exactly what @vzhen needs: your code in Firebase normally doesn't have to worry about "creating" vs "updating". Instead it simply "sets" the value and the parent node (uid in this case) gets created automatically. If that is also what you mean, do you mind elaborating a bit on it in your anwer?

Comment: Skipping is better than overriding, can it be achieved?